# Bootstrap alert-dismissible not showing in alert div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fpfn3zw/) where I am trying to overlay a bootstrap alert on a bootstrap well on a click event, but the 'alert-dismissible' close box isn't showing! How can I get this to show and how do I hide the alert message when the alert-dismissible 'x' is clicked?

```js
$('.well').on('click', function() {
  $('.alert').show();
  $('.alert').addcss('z-index: 1'); //.addClass('position: absolute');
})
```

```css
.well,
.alert {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well">Text Inside A Well</div>
<div style="display: none" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">Test</Div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_alerts_close&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

1.you missed the below HTML in alert `div`.

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

2.`addcss` is not function. It should be `css`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3fpfn3zw/2/)

3.The close button in above fiddle removes the `alert` div from DOM. If you want  reuse the `div` then check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fpfn3zw/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me without `javascript`/`jQuery`:

```
<div class="well">Text Inside A Well
<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>Test</div>
</div>
```